# Найти наибольшее значение в словаре

Tags: python

Всем привет.
Нужна помощь по поиску ключей с наибольшей датой в словаре.
Есть словарь ftp_json. Ключ это название файла, значение - дата {'rayon.arj': 'Jan-18-2007', 'RCLOSE.arj': 'Jun-23-2005', 'REAL.arj': 'Jun-23-2005', 'REASON.ARJ': 'Jan-29-2021', 'REGFAULT.arj': 'Oct-26-2015', 'ROS.ARJ': 'Nov-25-2019', 'ROSINKAS.ARJ': 'Feb-22-2022',...}. Он очень большой, там около 3000 ключей.
В этом словаре мне нужны ключи соответствующие названиям, которые хранятся в списке daily_updated. Причем, значения в словаре ftp_json представляют собой название + дата(mmdd) (kgrd0112, cvhd0522 и т.д).

```
daily_updated = ('kgrd', 'cvhd', 'metd')

for sprav in daily_updated:
    for arc_name, arc_date in ftp_json.items():
        arc_name = arc_name.lower()
        dateFormat = '%b-%d-%Y'
        rc_date = dt.strptime(arc_date, dateFormat)
```

Итого:

```
daily_updated = ('kgrd', 'cvhd', 'metd')

ftp_json = {'kgrd0118.arj': 'Jan-18-2007', 
 'kgrd0623.arj': 'Jun-23-2005', 
 'kgrd0624.arj': 'Jun-24-2005', 
 'cvhd0629.ARJ': 'Jan-29-2021', 
 'cvhd1026.arj': 'Oct-26-2015', 
 'cvhd1125.ARJ': 'Nov-25-2019', 
 'cvhd0222.ARJ': 'Feb-22-2022',
 'metd0228.ARJ': 'Feb-28-2022',
 'metd0321.ARJ': 'Mar-26-2021',
}


result = ['kgrd0118.arj', 'cvhd0222.arj', 'metd0228.ARJ']
```

Сколько есть масок в списке daily_updated , столько и результатов хочу получить.

Comment: приведите воспроизводимый пример исходных данных и пример того, что вы хотите получить в итоге, так будет проще понять ваши пожелания

Comment: Добавил правки в пост. Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

первое, что приходит в голову - это использовать модуль pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

ftp_json = {'kgrd0118.arj': 'Jan-18-2007', 
            'kgrd0623.arj': 'Jun-23-2005', 
            'kgrd0624.arj': 'Jun-24-2005', 
            'cvhd0629.ARJ': 'Jan-29-2021', 
            'cvhd1026.arj': 'Oct-26-2015', 
            'cvhd1125.ARJ': 'Nov-25-2019', 
            'cvhd0222.ARJ': 'Feb-22-2022',
            'metd0228.ARJ': 'Feb-28-2022',
            'metd0321.ARJ': 'Mar-26-2021'}

daily_updated = ('kgrd', 'cvhd', 'metd')

df = pd.DataFrame(ftp_json.items(), columns=['key','value'])
result = (df.groupby(df['key'].apply(lambda x: next(i for i in daily_updated if i in x))).
          apply(lambda x: df.loc[pd.to_datetime(x['value']).idxmax(),'key'])).tolist()

print(result)
'''
['cvhd0222.ARJ', 'kgrd0118.arj', 'metd0228.ARJ']
```

**upd**

а впрочем можно обойтись и без pandas:

```
from itertools import groupby
from datetime import datetime as dt

result = [max(g, key=lambda y: dt.strptime(y[1],'%b-%d-%Y'))[0] 
          for _,g in groupby(ftp_json.items(), 
                             lambda x: next(i for i in daily_updated if i in x[0]))]
```

Comment: Второй вариант выдает пустой список [ ].

Comment: @ChainSaw проверил с тем примером, что указан в вопросе - результат `['kgrd0118.arj', 'cvhd0222.ARJ', 'metd0228.ARJ']`